# Apache hosts; how to remove host name?

Tags: apache-2.2, hosts

I have two domains that are redirected to my server IP. I removed (I think) all entires from `/etc/apache/sites-available/*` that was responsible for resolving those host names.

Now when I'm trying to use this domains, they still redirects to this IP (and it's OK since domains are still assigned to it) but to certain folder I don't know and it results with 403.

What I expect:

**When I type the domain name in browser it should end with no server found.**

Are there any other places that I must search to eventually delete something?

Comment: If you want to have a "no server found" error you should remove the site entry from DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache will use the default configuration if there are no virtual hosts that match (or if virtual hosting is not enabled). You can find the directory with `grep -ri DocumentRoot /etc/apache`. The 403 error is likely caused by an empty DocumentRoot with `Options -Indexes`.

However, it sounds like you do not want to host any domains on this machine. If so, turn off Apache, remove any `Listen` directive (`grep -ri Listen /etc/apache`) or uninstall it.

---

NOTE the above assumes that Apache config files are located in /etc/apache However IIRC, the sites-available dir indicates that you're running Apache 2+ so, you may need to change paths to `/etc/apache2`

Comment: Thanks for replies. Indeed I need to remove it from DNS to have "no server found". And since I had deleted all vhosts it fallbacks to DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 1):

> Now when I'm trying to use this domains, they still redirects to this
>   IP (and it's OK since domains are still assigned to it) but to certain
>   folder I don't know and it results with 403.

And then you expect

> When I type the domain name in browser it should end with no server
>   found.

The DNS points to your webserver. Since there is a webserver listening, it replies
with whatever it has left (HTTP 403) which probably because of forbidden directory listing.

The other places you must search are DNS servers.

Depends on though on what you want to eventually delete

Answer (score 1):

After you change apache configuration, you should reload apache: `service apache2 reload`.

To test which vhosts are in the current file configuration (as opposed to the running one), run: `apache2ctl -D DUMP_VHOSTS -t`